How do i fix PHP headers?
How do i make it so that the page only redirects to data.php after the update query is submitted? when i click edit, it immediately redirects to data.php. But what i'am trying to do is when i click edit the update modal will pop up and when i finish the edits to be done and click update then and only then should the modal close and redirect.
i tried asking ai s but theyre suggestions dont work
beginner here so please enlighten me
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .modal {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 40%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            z-index: 2;
            width: 270px;
            height: 100px;
            max-width: 90%;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbsemi");
    $name = "";
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if (isset($_GET["txtname"])) {
        if (isset($_GET["txteditid"])) {
            $edit_id = $_GET["txteditid"];
            $edit_name = $_GET["txtname"];
            $edit_course = $_GET["txtcourse"];
            $edit_con = $_GET["txtcno"];
            $conn->query("UPDATE tbldata SET nams='$edit_name', cors='$edit_course', cno='$edit_con' WHERE id='$edit_id'");
            header("Location: data.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            $name = $_GET["txtname"];
            $course = $_GET["txtcourse"];
            $con = $_GET["txtcno"];
            $conn->query("INSERT INTO tbldata (nams, cors, cno) VALUES ('$name', '$course', '$con')");
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div id="modal" class="modal">
        <button onclick="closeModal()">x</button>
        <form method="get" action="data.php">
            Name: <input type="text" name="txtname" value='<?php echo $name; ?>' required><br>
            <?php if(isset($_GET["txteditid"])): ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="txteditid" value='<?php echo $_GET["txteditid"]; ?>'>
                Course:
            <select name="txtcourse" required>
                <option value="CPE">CPE</option>
                <option value="CCS">CCS</option>
                <option value="BSBA">BSBA</option>
            </select><br>
            ContactNo: <input type="text" name="txtcno" required><br>
            <input type="submit" value="UPDATE" onclick="closeModal()">

            <?php else: ?>
            Course:
            <select name="txtcourse" required>
                <option value="CPE">CPE</option>
                <option value="CCS">CCS</option>
                <option value="BSBA">BSBA</option>
            </select><br>
            ContactNo: <input type="text" name="txtcno" required><br>
            <input type="submit" value="ADD">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </form>
    </div>

    <button onclick="displayModal()">+</button>

    <table>
        <a href="print.php"><button>PRINT</button></a>
        <tr>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>ContactNo</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbldata");
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
                echo "<tr>
                <td><a href='data.php?txteditid={$row["id"]}&txtname={$row["nams"]}&txtcourse={$row["cors"]}&txtcno={$row["cno"]}'><button>EDIT</button></a></td>
                <td>{$row["nams"]}</td>
                <td>{$row["cors"]}</td>
                <td>{$row["cno"]}</td>
                </tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
    <script>
        function displayModal() {
           let modal = document.getElementById('modal');
           modal.style.display = 'block';
           
        }
        function closeModal() {
            let modal = document.getElementById('modal');
            modal.style.display = 'none';
         
        }
   </script>
   <?PHP
        if (isset($_GET["txteditid"])){
            echo  " <script>
                    let m = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
                    m.style.display = 'block';
                    </script>";
        }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>

i tried removing the header but the modal will not close automatically and the url will still have the previous query's isset

Totally unrelated to your problem, but I just wanted to make sure you were aware that modern HTML has a dedicated modal element called dialog. It is a great accessibility win over traditional JS-based modals.

So you've got a form on a page. It happens to be in a modal, but that doesn't matter. When you click the button, you want the database query to happen before the redirect. Your browser is processing the FORM's action directive in a native fashion. If you want to stop that, you will need to process the form with JS and ajax/fetch, and block the form's native submission. Alternatively, split your processing and display into two files. The processing only does updates/inserts and always redirects back to the display, possibly with a query string reflecting what happened.

thank you i'll try incorporating it

Just move form processing at the very top. It just makes no sense to output <!DOCTYPE html> and stuff if you want to do a redirect. So you should process your form above this HTML

....and read up on SQL injection.
